# Redis docker-compose with Nodejs - connect ENOENT

Tags: node.js, docker, redis, docker-compose

I am trying to containerize my whole developer workflow using `docker-compose`. Problem I am facing is with `redis` contianer. My worker container is unable to connect to redis. I trie different solution from stackoverflow like:

[Setting up node with redis using docker-compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56533022/setting-up-node-with-redis-using-docker-compose)

[Access redis locally on docker - docker compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52246220/access-redis-locally-on-docker-docker-compose)

[nodejs, redis, npm and docker-compose setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43488601/nodejs-redis-npm-and-docker-compose-setup)

[Docker-compose , anyway to specify a redis.conf file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30547274/docker-compose-anyway-to-specify-a-redis-conf-file)

[How to connect to a Redis container using Docker Compose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42376867/how-to-connect-to-a-redis-container-using-docker-compose)

And many others also from github, tried different examples but no luck.

Here is my docker-compose file:

```yaml
version: "3.6"

services:
  redis_db:
    # image: bitnami/redis:latest # tried different image also
    image: redis
    container_name: rme_redis
    network_mode: host # tried networks also
    # command: ['redis-server', '/redis.conf']
    # volumes:
    #   - ./docker/redis.conf:/redis.conf
    # hostname: redis_db
    # networks: 
    #   - rme
    # environment:
    #   - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
      # - REDIS_PASSWORD="redis"
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
    # networks:
    #   node_net:
    #     ipv4_address: 172.28.1.4

  worker:
    build: worker
    image: worker
    container_name: rme_worker
    command: node worker.js
    # networks:
    #   - rme
    # network_mode: host
    environment: 
      - REDIS_URL="redis://redis_db:6379" # localhost when netowk_mode is host
    volumes:
      - ./worker:/app
    # links:
    #   - redis_db
    depends_on:
      - redis_db
```

Error I am getting is:

```sh
Error: Redis connection to "redis://redis_db:6379" failed - connect ENOENT "redis://redis_db:6379"
     at PipeConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1141:16) {
   errno: -2,
   code: 'ENOENT',
   syscall: 'connect',
   address: '"redis://redis_db:6379"'
 }
```

Operating system: macOS

Docker: Docker Desktop

Edit: Found a solution using host and port in js code

```js
const redisClient = redis.createClient({
  host: process.env.REDIS_HOST,
  port: parseInt(process.env.REDIS_PORT)
})
```

```yaml
# docker-compose.yml
version: "3.6"
services:
  redis_db:
    image: redis
    # only needed to directly access Redis from host
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
  worker:
    build: worker
    environment: 
      - REDIS_HOST=redis_db
      - REDIS_PORT=6379
    depends_on:
      - redis_db
```

If you find solution using redis connection string do share.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3):

Setting `network_mode: host` disables Docker networking for a specific container.  It's only necessary in some unusual situations where a container doesn't listen on a fixed port number or where you're trying to use a container to manage the host's network setup.

In your case, since the Redis database is disabling Docker networking, the application container can't reach it by name.  Removing all of the `network_mode: host` options should address this.

[Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) describes the overall network setup.  Of note, Compose will create a `default` network for you, and containers will be reachable using their Compose service names.  You shouldn't normally need to specify custom `networks:` options, explicitly provide a `container_name:`, set a `hostname:`, provide archaic `links:`, or set `network_mode:`.

You should be able to successfully trim the `docker-compose.yml` file you show down to:

```yaml
version: "3.6"
services:
  redis_db:
    image: redis
    # only needed to directly access Redis from host
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
  worker:
    build: worker
    environment: 
      - REDIS_URL="redis://redis_db:6379"
    # `docker-compose up worker` also starts Redis
    # Not strictly needed for networking
    depends_on:
      - redis_db
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, tried your solution but still same error `Error: Redis connection to "redis://redis_db:6379" failed - connect ENOENT "redis://redis_db:6379"`, redis log `* Ready to accept connections`, operating system is macos and using docker-desktop.

Comment: Is your code trying to use `REDIS_URL` as a host name?  (Does setting `REDIS_URL=redis_db` help, even though that's not a URL?)

Comment: No its url passed to redis library, `redis.createClient({ url: process.env.REDIS_URL })`